# Сложные вопросы про Python !

Tags: python, сравнение, java

Граждане, после некоторых знаний Java\C# изучаю Python посматриваю немного на Ruby для разнообразия но не суть. Почитал немного книжичек так и не понял где у Python : интерфейсы, параметризированные типы, нормальные коллекции, как сделать абстрактный или статический класс\метод, почему я не могу задать публичность или приватность локальным типам, где эти все фишки и как их включить ?

Comment: Прочитайте бОльше книжек. Все описанное- основы языка, все это есть и это не надо нигде включать.

Comment: Как по мне так это как-то надо включить ибо когда я хочу создать интерфейс и пишу : interface - это ошибка, когда пишу public class Zhopa, то слово public - это тоже ошибка !

Comment: И вообще за что меня минусовать, я задал вполне нормальный вопрос !

Comment: >И вообще за что меня минусовать, я задал вполне нормальный вопрос !

рискну предположить, что вас заминусовали за то, что ваш вопрос явно не тянет на "Сложные вопросы" (даже мне, человеку, в глаза не видевшему Python, это очевидно)

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы Питон был как Java, только с другим синтаксисом. Вы даже хотите, чтобы ключевые слова были те же. Это не так, Питон — _существенно_ другой язык, и паттерны, о которых вы говорите, реализуются на Питоне по-другому. Зачем был бы нужен Питон, если он был бы просто Java-без-фигурных-скобок?

Comment: >Зачем был бы нужен Питон, если бы он был просто Java-без-фигурных-скобок?

    <петроcян_mode> 
        Может, затем, зачем есть C#? C фигурными скобками между прочим
    </петросян_mode>

Comment: Вопрос дурацкий, ибо отпадает сам собой после вдумчивого прочтения превых глав любого учебника по Python. Именно в превых главах обычно объясняется, что Python - _динамически типизированный язык_ (само собой, там же объясняется, что это такое), а значит, в нём совершенно не нужны: 

 1. интерфейсы (ведь вы можете вызвать любой метод у любого объекта, даже не будучи твёрдо уверенным, что этот метод существует);
 2. параметризированные типы (в C# они обычно используются для создания коллекций, в Python же в коллекции можно смело добавлять объекты любых типов, в том числе и разных);

Comment: 3. уровни доступа для полей и методов (язык не только динамически типизированный, но и интерпретируемый, с глубокой интроспекцикей, спрятать ничего не получится).

К тому же непонятно, чем вам не угодили коллекции в Python. Можете описать, чем они ненормальны, представить критерии нормальности коллекций в языках программирования?

Comment: Вопрос демонстрирует узость вашего мышления, попытки подогнать один язык программирования под понятия совершенно другого, исповедующего другие принципы и методологии разработки. Вы, даже не пытаясь понять этого ишете в новом языке элементы уже вам известного, а не найдя - возмущаетесь, свято веря в то, что известный вам язык единственный правильный. Отсюда минусы и негативные комментарии.

Comment: @DreamChild:

    <зануда mode>
        C# появился, как известно, в качестве ответа на нежелание
        фирмы Sun добавлять делегаты в язык.
    </зануда mode>

Comment: Ну в общем понял ...

Comment: Всё сказанное относится и к Ruby ?

Comment: безумный вопрос. Изучите сначала в достаточной степени 1 язык, чем сразу несколько(причем даже не языков, а серьезных технологий) но плохо. У вас ничего в голове не уляжется и скоро все забудете.

Answer (score 13):

Читайте литературу. Это другой язык. Если где-то есть что-то, это не значит, что должно быть тоже самое где-то ещё. Смысл питона в том что в нём нет того, без чего и так можно нормально работать. Здесь есть соглашение об именовании и этого достаточно.

Мир языков программирования очень большой и потому большой, что они разные, а не просто тоже самое другими словами. Они разные по идеологии, парадигме, подходу к парадигме и т.д. Как говорил Морфей: «Раскрой свой разум». Программирование гораздо больше чем кажется на первый взгляд.

Comment: А ещё можно слайды посмотреть: http://norvig.com/design-patterns/design-patterns.pdf (это на тему модных шаблонов проектирования)

Comment: То есть в Питоне этого всего просто нет (интерфейсы, абстрактные классы итд) ....

Comment: В питоне есть множественное наследование, метаклассы, декораторы, инъекция кода, передача функции как параметра, соглашение об именовании, полная интроспекция итд…

Comment: Интерфейсы в Питоне просто не нужны

Comment: @MAX_Vovk 

     То есть в Питоне этого всего просто нет (интерфейсы, абстрактные классы итд) ....

Ага, а трактор не даёт навоза, удобрять поля нечем. Лошадь лучше.

Answer (score -1):

если честно не знал что программы пишутся интерфейсами, типами и коллекциями....

Считаю что язык это только средство записи алгоритмов, а следовательно не важно какой язык и не важно как написан код и чем, важно что бы он выполнял свою работу на отлично.

П.С. то есть не важно если у пользователя доступ какому то параметру или то что все данные у вас зашифрованы... по сути это уже не работа программиста, а работа секъюрити отдела защитить вашу программу от несанкционированного вмешательства в ее работу.

Это к тому что та область которую вы рассматриваете, не так важна как другие аспекты любого языка.

Comment: Язык программирования сильно на мозги влияет. Кроме того, выбор языка -- это не только выбор инструмента, но и выбор сообщества (П. Грэм). Там много чего можно обсуждать.